How to remove visually perceivable non-contiguous horizontal lines from scanned image of a table?
The source image contains a table on which I performed erosion/dilation using horizontal and vertical kernel to find/detect horizontal and vertical lines. Then I used findContours and drawContours function to hide the lines.
Problem: I am processing various images with varying thickness of horizontal/vertical lines. I am using a 10 pixel sized brush to draw over these vertical/horizontal lines which for some images is not enough and leaves some of the lines visible.
How can I remove these remaining lines in a way that does not modify the characters?
original source image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P8Aw54BEHaWcZQUHvKO7h54WRXYf7-MR/view?usp=sharing
source image (downgraded due to SO size restriction):

transformed image:

edit(added original code):
import cv2
import imutils
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import numpy as np

debug = True


image = cv2.imread('HAL.jpg')
# origin = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# print(thresh)  # two values are 0 for black, and 255 for white

mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, np.uint8)
mask.fill(255)

origin = thresh.copy()

# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 40))

if debug:
    cv2.imshow("before removing vlines", imutils.resize(thresh, width=800))
    cv2.waitKey(0)


morph_iterations = 4
remove_vertical = thresh.copy()

# manually check what iteration of erode/dilate will be give good result

# removes all text
for _ in range(2):
    remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(
        remove_vertical, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, vertical_kernel, iterations=1
    )
    if debug:
        cv2.imshow("see runtime changes", imutils.resize(remove_vertical, width=800))
        cv2.waitKey(0)

# dilate to complete broken lines
for _ in range(morph_iterations*2):
    remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(
        remove_vertical, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, vertical_kernel, iterations=1
    )
    if debug:
        cv2.imshow("see runtime changes", imutils.resize(remove_vertical, width=800))
        cv2.waitKey(0)

# undo dilation using half iteration to keep incomplete lines
for _ in range(morph_iterations//2):
    remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(
        remove_vertical, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, vertical_kernel, iterations=1
    )
    if debug:
        cv2.imshow("see runtime changes", imutils.resize(remove_vertical, width=800))
        cv2.waitKey(0)

contours = cv2.findContours(remove_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

for c in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(origin, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 10)
    # cv2.drawContours(source_image, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), 10)

if debug:
    cv2.imshow("after drawing contours on source", imutils.resize(origin, width=800))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Remove horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (40, 1))

if debug:
    cv2.imshow("before removing hlines", imutils.resize(thresh, width=800))
    cv2.waitKey(0)


morph_iterations = 4
remove_horizontal = thresh.copy()

# removes all text
for _ in range(2):
    remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(
        remove_horizontal, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1
    )
    if debug:
        cv2.imshow("see runtime changes", imutils.resize(remove_horizontal, width=800))
        cv2.waitKey(0)

# dilate to complete broken lines
for _ in range(morph_iterations*2):
    remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(
        remove_horizontal, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1
    )
    if debug:
        cv2.imshow("see runtime changes", imutils.resize(remove_horizontal, width=800))
        cv2.waitKey(0)


for _ in range(morph_iterations//2):
    remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(
        remove_horizontal, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1
    )
    if debug:
        cv2.imshow("see runtime changes", imutils.resize(remove_horizontal, width=800))
        cv2.waitKey(0)


contours = cv2.findContours(remove_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

for c in contours:
    # cv2.drawContours(remove_horizontal, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.drawContours(origin, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 10)
    # cv2.drawContours(source_image, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), 10)

if 'debug':
    cv2.imshow("after drawing contours on source", imutils.resize(origin, width=800))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

square_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))

# try different configs of dilate/erode 
i_counter = 0
while True:
    i_counter += 1
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 106:

        origin = cv2.morphologyEx(
            origin, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, square_kernel, iterations=1
        )
    if key == 107:

        origin = cv2.morphologyEx(
            origin, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, square_kernel, iterations=1
        )

    if key == 108:

        # create a mask
        mask = cv2.morphologyEx(
            origin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1
        )

        cv2.imshow("noise after erode", imutils.resize(mask, width=600))

        # update the mask
        mask = cv2.morphologyEx(
            mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, square_kernel, iterations=1
        )
        cv2.imshow("noise after dilate", imutils.resize(mask, width=600))
        # cv2.imshow("origin - mask", imutils.resize(origin-mask, width=800))

        origin-=mask
        # origin = cv2.absdiff(origin, origin1)
        # origin = cv2.bitwise_xor(origin, origin1)


    cv2.imshow(f"results", imutils.resize(origin, width=600))

    # Shuts down the display window and terminates
    # the Python process when a specific key is
    # pressed on the window.
    # 27 is the esc key
    # 113 is the letter 'q'
    if key == 27 or key == 113:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I tried to thicken the lines and subtract from image but it did not made any significant difference and performing multiple iteration of it causes white thick lines on image. Any ides on how to rectify this are welcome.
    # create a mask
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(
        transformed_img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1
    )

    cv2.imshow("noise after erode", imutils.resize(mask, width=600))

    # update the mask
    # using square kernel of 2x2 to thicken the lines
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(
        mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, square_kernel, iterations=1
    )
    cv2.imshow("noise after dilate", imutils.resize(mask, width=600))

    transformed_img -= mask


should we consider that all your images have horizontal text, so no-deskew operation should be performed?

@cards yes all of them have horizontal texts as they all follow same result format but with different layouts of table. some tables are skewed but I already wrote the fn to deskew them.

Has the source image been downsampled on upload? Many horizontal lines are discontinuous. If they are continuous in the original image, the problem is a lot simpler.

assuming A4, ratio fits, scan is ~210 dpi and mask is exactly 300 dpi. the mask has discontinuous lines too.

@CrisLuengo updated the post with the original image. had to downgrade the image due to stackoverflow size limit.

the source image is binarized already. you should scan in grayscale instead. then you'll have a better chance of capturing those lines properly. -- I think an appropriate mix of morphology operations might be able to erase the lines from what you have so far. -- AI will likely be more successful, and easier to handle, than hand-crafted approaches.

@ChristophRackwitz make sense, but the quality of image is not something I can control.  I extracted the image from pdf. Are you aware of any AI service I can try?

I doubt there's an "AI service" for this specific problem. you'll have to devise and train your own model. synthetic data should be easy to cook up, real data easy to augment. just generate tables with random text in them, with the horizontal lines having random noise breaking them, and teach the network to directly infer the cleaned up image. something fully convolutional should work fine. with skip connections of course, something auto-encoderish, except it encodes information on what image features to suppress.

There is a possibility to use the strongest of the vertical and horizontal lines to determine a small deskew (and/or keystone) correction that together will make the lines more accurately horizontal and vertical. It is off by about 0.5 degrees visually . The other option is sum the data in columns and shift each scan line to keep the centroids of continuous vertical lines at fixed positions. They run out badly. Horizontal lines are not so far out (so a simple rotation would have to be a compromise). A small sideways shift per line would get you out of that bind and is quick.
